# Difference between MATCH (field1, field2) and MATCH(field1) OR MATCH(field2)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Is there a difference in results between the two below queries?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
    ( MATCH(table1.row1) AGAINST('searchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
    OR
    ( MATCH(table2.row2) AGAINST('searchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )


SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
    ( MATCH(table1.row1, table2.row2) AGAINST('searchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
```

I prefer the first approach, as that makes it more easy for me to implement ranking criteria for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the second query is an error.

The `MATCH()` function's arguments must be *all* the columns for which *one* fulltext index is defined.

But indexes cannot be defined over multiple tables. Therefore an exppression like  `MATCH(table1.row1, table2.row2)` can't work, because it references columns from two different tables.

---

If you reference only columns from the same table, then it's okay to put multiple columns in a `MATCH()` function. In fact, it's *mandatory* if the fulltext index was defined over multiple columns. Note that above, I said that the function's arguments must be *all* columns for a fulltext index.

Comment: What if I use fields within the same table then?